# Replace n*expression by n-times the expression

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I want to expand n*expression to n times the expression, for example:

`3*2.5 3.4 4*1.5`

to

`2.5 2.5 2.5 3.4 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5`

I tried sed and awk, but was far from any solution.

My closest trial was

`cat test3times | awk -e '$1 ~ /[0-9]\*/ {print $0, $0, $0}'`

But that still has the 3* in front of the expression included and does not change for 4*
Also it does not print the other parts such as the 3.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    split($i,arr,"*")
    count=0
    while(++count<=arr[1]){
      if(count==1){val=""}
      val=(val?val OFS:"")arr[2]
    }
    $i=(val?val:$i)
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
2.5 2.5 2.5 3.4 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                 ##Starting for loop till till value of NF(number of  fields) here.
    split($i,arr,"*")                 ##Splitting current field into array named arr with delimiter of * here.
    count=0                           ##Nullify count here.
    while(++count<=arr[1]){           ##Running while loop from count 1 till value of arr first element value.
      if(count==1){val=""}
      val=(val?val OFS:"")arr[2]      ##Creating val which has value of 2nd array element(which is digit after * actually in field)
    }
    $i=(val?val:$i)                   ##Saving value in current field itself.
  }
}
1                                     ##Mentioning 1 will print current line here.
' Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( split($i,a,/[*]/) == 2 ) {
            list = ""
            for (j=1; j<=a[1]; j++) {
                list = (j>1 ? list OFS : "") a[2]
            }
            $i = list
        }
    }
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
2.5 2.5 2.5 3.4 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5
```

Comment: can you think of a "cool" way to do it more succinctly gawk's ```gensub``` or simillar (without a loop). I've been puzzled here trying different things :```{ print "[" gensub(/([[:digit:]]+)\*([[:digit:].]+)/, "\\2", "G", sprintf("%*s", 15,"")) "]"}``` with hardwired repetition... Cannot get my head around it....